# What is @ symbol in scala pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I've been looking at someone's [code](https://github.com/piotrga/async-dynamo/blob/master/src/main/scala/com.github.piotrga/asyncdynamo/Dynamo.scala) and noticed this

```
case overdue @ PendingOperation(operation, _) => ......
```

What does @ symbol mean here? How is it called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called *variable binding*.
It binds the value being matched on to the `overdue` variable.

In this way you can both destructure the value by pattern matching over it and later reference it as a whole.

While it's not particularly useful in a case like

```
foo match {
  case a @ Bar(baz, bar) => ...
}
```

since you can directly refer to `foo`, it gets more interesting in cases like

```
foo match {
  case Bar(b @ Baz("hello", _), _) => ...
}
```

where you bind an inner match to a variable.